# Why am I getting the error 'cannot access private member declared in class' even though I have declared friend class

Tags: c++, friend

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class A
{
    private:
        T value;

    public:
        A(T v){ value = v;}

        friend class A<int>;
};

template<typename T>
class B
{
    public:
        T method(A<T> a){ return a.value; }  // problem here, but why?
};

int main()
{
    A<int> a(2);
    B<int> b;

    std::cout << b.method(a) << std::endl;
}
```

Why do I still get the error: "'A::value': cannot access private member declared in class 'A'" even though I have declared A as a friend class for the template type int?

***Edit***
Note that moving the friend class line inside B also does not work:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
    private:
        T value;

    public:
        A(T v){ value = v; }
};

template<typename T>
class B
{
    public:
    T method(A<T> a){ return a.value; }

    friend class A<int>;
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be in class B

Comment: You need to allow B to access A's private data.

Comment: `friend class A<int>;` why do you limit to `<int>` instead of `<typename T>`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I could do that however I dont think that is the actual problem. The reason is because in my actual code this is part of a math library and I plan on having friends for int, float, double, complex. This is just a simple example that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<typename T>
class B;

template<typename T>
class A
{
    private:
        T value;
    public:
        A(T v){ value = v;}
        friend class B<int>;
};

template<typename T>
class B
{
    public:
        T method(A<T> a){ return a.value; }
};
```

The class A should have class B as a friend , if you want B to use A's private attributes.

Comment: That's correct as is the forward-declaration of `template<typename T>class B;` prior to the definition of `template<typename T>class A {...}`. Note, the location of `friend class B<int>;` in the definition of `class A` isn't important and `friend class B<T>;` is all that is needed rather than `<int>`.

Comment: Thanks! I would have thought the opposite where class B would need to have class A as a friend in order to access class A's private data. Instead it was the opposite where class A needs class B as a friend.

Comment: you could have also used a friend method : `friend T B<T>::method(A<T>);`  but I do not know how to force the constraint to the int type with this approach ... :/

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class A
{
    private:
        T value;

    public:
        A(T v){ value = v;}
        T getValue() { return value; }


};

template<typename T>
class B
{
    public:
        friend class A<int>;
        T method(A<T> a){ return a.getValue(); } 

};

int main()
{
    A<int> a(2);
    B<int> b;

    std::cout << b.method(a) << std::endl;
}
```

Few changes. a.value() value is a private member variable, so we created a getter below getValue() and replaced where needed. 
Also moved friend class A to class B.

Comment: If I am going to use a getter, then why would I need to declare a friend class at all?

Comment: @James, I don't think you understand what friend is for. Friend does not override access levels...

Comment: @Omd CompSCI My understanding is that friend allows you to access private members from outside the class as long as you are a friend of the class containing the private members. With your solution I can just delete the "friend class" line and it will still work since you are just using a standard getter. So again I guess my question to you is, what is the point of the "friend class" line in your solution...

Answer (score 0):

```
T method(A<T> a){ return a.value; }
```

> problem here, but why?

Because `class` `B` is accessing `class` `A`'s `private` member `value`.

Comment: Can you provide a solution. I tried moving the friend class A<int> into B but this does not fix the problem. I also tried having the A declared as a friend in both A and B and that also does not work. Perhaps I am missing something obvious and a explicit solution could help me.

Comment: Don't make `value` `private` since you obviously want to access it from other `class`s.

Comment: I don't want to make it public because I don't want it accessible from ALL classes though, only a small selection of related classes. Thats why I was going to use "friend". I could of course use a getter as I think suggested by Omid CompSCI